# Create a program that can find the nearest hundreds for a given number

Tags: python

I'm using the def function and the for or the while loop to create a program that can find the nearest hundreds for a given number.

Comment: Try dividing by 100 -> Rounding -> Multipling by 100 -> convert to int

Comment: You just need [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). Look at the result of `print(round(155, -2))`.